# Move value from one jsp to another via submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have fetched the table names from database in `ComboBox` . Now I want to transfer the selected `ComboBox` value to new jsp page when the submit button will be clicked. how can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try ? Just google it and you will get many answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

suppose first abc.jsp is having below comboBox

```
<select id="projectName" name="projectName">
        <option value="KCC">KCC</option>
        <option value="SunAmerica">Sun America</option>
        <option value="UHC">UHC</option>
        <option value="Ironman">Ironman</option>
        <option value="John Varvatos">John Varvatos</option>
        <option value="Steven Alan">Steven Alan</option>
        <option value="SingPost">SingPost</option>
        <option value="LVMH">LVMH</option>
        <option value="Blissworld">Blissworld</option>
        <option value="CED">CED</option>
        <option value="Coravin">Coravin</option>
        <option value="Mgemi">Mgemi</option>

    </select>
```

once you submit you can get the value on second jsp as

```
String projectName = request.getParameter("projectName");
```